# Type 'Budget[]' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Budget[]>' Property 'then' is missing in type 'Budget[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I need to return `Promise<Budget[]>`. But it shows error as:

> [ts] Type 'Budget[]' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>   Property 'then' is missing in type 'Budget[]'. let budgets: Budget[]

Could you tell me how can I return a `Promise<Budget[]>` from below method?

```
 createBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Promise<Budget[]> {
    let budgets: Budget[] = [];
    forEach(data, async (d) => {
      const budgetId: string = this.fireStore.createId();
      d.id = budgetId;
      budgets.push(d);
      await this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${budgetId}`).set({
        id: budgetId,
        amount: d.amount,
        contingency: d.contingency,
        budgetGroup: d.budgetGroup,
        creationTime: moment().format()
      });
    });
    return budgets;// error shows here?
  }
```

Comment: Familiar with `Promise.resolve()` and or `.toPromise()`? This isn't exactly a conventional way of doing this

Comment: Could you post your solution, please? @Z.Bagley

Comment: General idea is that you declare `budgets: Budget[]`, when it should be a Promise. Why not just define `createBudgets()` as a `Budget[]`? You're already handling the async with your await, so you have access to the data w/o the promise. Hope this helps

Comment: The problem here is, I need to get the `budgets` after those were stored in the db. Not before it. If I just use `Budget[]` then it returns before persisting the data in the db. So I need to avoid that. Do you know how can I do that? @Z.Bagley

Comment: Yes, set your `await` to a variable (`const myAwait = await ...`), and return the variable instead. I'm slightly confused on your "Overall plan" here though, and thinking you might be trying to reinvent a wheel here. I'd have to assume that `fireStore` has a way to return a promise w/o use of `await` (already implemented method), but I don't use this library

Comment: Nope, It doesn't return anything. That is the issue here. It just returns `Promise<void>`. That is why I need to use a custom array to fetch the data. If I have one item then I can do that. But here I have to iterate a loop (`forEach`). That is the issue. Don't I have another method to handle this kind of use cases? @Z.Bagley

Comment: Here I have another issue. Any help there too? @Z.Bagley https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472351/run-a-promise-at-once-and-wait-till-it-executes

Comment: I'm overloaded on work atm, might have time tomorrow to look into this for you though sorry

Comment: OK sure. Thanks a lot for the help @Z.Bagley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for all the `set` method invocations to finish execution, you need to add them in an array, and use `Promise.all` to wait until they finish:

```
async createBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Promise<Budget[]> {
    let budgets : Budget[] = [];
    await Promise.all(data.map(async (d) => {
        const budgetId: string = this.fireStore.createId();
        d.id = budgetId;
        budgets.push(d);
        await this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${budgetId}`).set({
            id: budgetId,
            amount: d.amount,
            contingency: d.contingency,
            budgetGroup: d.budgetGroup,
            creationTime: moment().format()
        });
    }));
    return budgets;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)